# Vector Calculus Identity with multiplicative scalar fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, substitution

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a vector identity to expand the following expression:

$$
\nabla\times\left(\phi\nabla\times\psi\boldsymbol{A}\right)
$$

where $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a vector field, and $\phi$ and $\psi$ are scalar fields. All three fields vary with position. Is there a way to use the $\nabla\times\left(\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B}\right)$ identity? I don't think I can just use a substitution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that there is any known identity, and that expanding the curl makes things easy. Why do you want to expand it? You can still introduce $\boldsymbol F = \nabla \times (\psi\boldsymbol A)$ and apply the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)) for $\nabla\times(\phi \boldsymbol F)$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking for an identity to check my working. I expanded using the substitution you suggested and then checked explicitly with the matrix notation. I wasn’t sure if I could use the curl(A cross B) = div(BA^T -AB^T) when a or b was the gradient operator and wanted to just verify. I checked and you can.